# Let $G$ be a group, $H ,N\le G$ and $N\unlhd G$. Show if $N$ is abelian and $G=NH$ then $N\cap H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a group, $H ,N$ subgroup and $N$ normal in $G$. Show if $N$ is abelian and $G = NH$ then $N\cap H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

$N\cap H $ is a normal  subgroup of $G$  means that if I take $g\in G$ and $a \in  N \cap H$,  then  $gag^{-1} \in N \cap H$

But $g=n_1h_1$ so $(n_1h_1)a(h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1})$ if $a\in N$,  $(n_1h_1)a(h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1}) \in N$ because $N$ is normal in fact $h_1ah_1^{-1}\in N$

But I don't know  how to use abelianity of $N$ to prove that  $(n_1h_1)a(h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1}) \in H$

Comment: Note that you should show that $N\cap H\leqslant G$ first.

Comment: with that notation are you referring the fact that intersection is a subgroup? I alredy know it is a subgroup because it is intersection of 2 subgroups

Comment: Exactly! I wanted to be sure that you already knew that. Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $(n_1h_1)a(h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1})=n_1h_1a(h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1}h_1h_1^{-1})=$
$n_1h_1(h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1}h_1)ah_1^{-1}$ (by the commutativity of $N$) $ = h_1ah_1^{-1}\in H$ because $a, h_1\in H$. Q.E.D. One can do a shorter derivation:

$$(n_1h_1)a(h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1})=n_1(h_1ah_1^{-1})n_1^{-1}=n_1n_1^{-1}(h_1ah_1^{-1})=h_1ah_1^{-1}$$